# Selecting columns based on date in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am very new to Sharepoint. I am working on a resource utilization list in Sharepoint , which helps managers keep a tab on utilization of their resources for each month . My list therefore has 12 columns for each month of the year. I want to create a view where in only the future 5 months from the current month are displayed. Therefore for example if the current month is August, I want only August,September,October,November and December columns to be displayed and the other month columns hidden.